# Как отсортировать массив объектов учитывая несколько параметров?

Tags: javascript, сортировка

У меня есть массив с объектами содержащий два свойства name и level. Мне нужно произвести его сортировку так, что бы объекты были по возрастанию от level = 1 до level = 3 и так далее, но что бы объекты с level = 0 были в самом конце. Но есть еще одно условие, если объекты имеют одинаковый level, то нужно  группировать их по name, что бы они находились рядом.

```
// пример массива
var army = [
{name: "archer", level: 1},
{name: "spearman", level: 1},
{name: "knight", level: 3},
{name: "swordsman", level: 2},
{name: "archer", level: 1},
{name: "none", level: 0},
]

// простая функция сортировки учитывающая, что lvl = 0 должен быть в конце
function comparelvl(a, b) {
    if (a.level > b.level) { 
        if (b.level != 0 ) return 1;
        else return -1 
    }
    if (a.level < b.level) {
        if (a.level != 0 ) return -1;
        else return 1;
    }
}

army.sort(comparelvl);
```

Как мне изменить функцию, comparelvl, что бы она не только сортировала объекты по уровню, но и помещала объекты у которых одинаковые имена рядом? Либо в идеале, как мне сделать сортировку сходных по уровню объектов еще и по имени (алфавиту).

То есть в результате, сортировки должно получиться так. 
Правильно:

```
army = [
{name: "archer", level: 1},
{name: "archer", level: 1},
{name: "spearman", level: 1},
{name: "swordsman", level: 2},
{name: "knight", level: 3},
{name: "none", level: 0},
]
```

Неправильно:

```
army = [
    {name: "archer", level: 1},
    {name: "spearman", level: 1}, // объект с другим именем посередине
    {name: "archer", level: 1},
    {name: "swordsman", level: 2},
    {name: "knight", level: 3},
    {name: "none", level: 0},
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```
function comparelvl(a, b) {
    if(a.level == b.level) {
        if(a.name == b.name) return 0;
        else if(a.name > b.name) return -1;
        else return 1;
    }
    else if (a.level > b.level) { 
        if (b.level != 0 ) return 1;
        else return -1 
    }
    else // if (a.level < b.level) {
        if (a.level != 0 ) return -1;
        else return 1;
    }
}
```

Я мог ошибиться с порядком возрастание/убывание, но это уже сами.

Comment: С порядком все правильно, функция работает как нужно. Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
function comparelvl(a, b) {
    if (a.level === b.level) {
        return a.name > b.name;
    } else if (a.level === 0) {
        return 1;
    } else if (b.level === 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    return a.level > b.level;
}

army.sort(comparelvl).map(e => { return `{level: ${e.level}, name: ${e.name}}`});
```

получается

```
"{level: 1, name: archer}"
"{level: 1, name: archer}"
"{level: 1, name: spearman}"
"{level: 2, name: swordsman}"
"{level: 3, name: knight}"
"{level: 0, name: none}"
```